# Not able to download packages-microsoft-prod.deb in ubuntu server

Tags: networking, 20.04, microsoft, dotnet

I am attempting to install using the following command:

`wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

However, the download process is getting stuck, and I am unable to complete it. The logs show that the connection to packages.microsoft.com at IP address 40.114.136.21 on port 443 (HTTPS) is timing out.

Here is a snippet of the log:

> --2023-07-27 16:51:29--  https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
> Resolving packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)... 40.114.136.21
> Connecting to packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)|40.114.136.21|:443...

After waiting for some time, I receive the following error:

> Connecting to packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)|40.114.136.21|:443... failed: Connection timed out. Retrying.
> --2023-07-27 16:53:41--  (try: 2)  https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
> Connecting to packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)|40.114.136.21|:443...

I have verified that both incoming and outgoing traffic for port 443 is allowed, and my internet connection is functioning correctly.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue so I can successfully download the packages-microsoft-prod.deb file from the Microsoft package repository. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Connection timed out" means that *something* is blocking the traffic, either your firewall or the router your network is connected to, or your ISP.  I can confirm that IP and URL works here, so it might be specific to your network/ISP

Comment: @ThomasWard-OnStrike how can i find which one is stopping it?